# spring aop pointcut not triggered

Tags: spring-aop

The issue is the @Before and @AfterReturning are working but it's not the case for Pointcut.

Here is my aspect.

As part of a springboot service, What I want do is trigger the pointcut with first method **profile** to show execution time and other things.

Am I missing something ?

```
package com.myproj.service.myagg.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

/**
 * Created by shammami on 26/05/2017.
 */
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingService {

    @Pointcut("execution(public void com.myproj.service.myagg.listener.MyMessageConsumer.handleMessage(..))")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        boolean isExceptionThrown = false;
        try {
            // execute the profiled method
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            isExceptionThrown = true;
            throw e;
        } finally {
            stopWatch.stop();
            StopWatch.TaskInfo taskInfo = stopWatch.getLastTaskInfo();
            // Log the method's profiling result
            String profileMessage = taskInfo.getTaskName() + ": " + taskInfo.getTimeMillis() + " ms" +
                    (isExceptionThrown ? " (thrown Exception)" : "");
            System.out.println(profileMessage);
        }
    }

    @Before("execution(public void com.myproj.service.myagg.listener.MyMessageConsumer.handleMessage(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Started: " + joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature().toLongString());
    }

    @AfterReturning("execution(public void com.myproj.service.myagg.listener.MyMessageConsumer.handleMessage(..))")
    public void completed(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Completed: " + joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature().toLongString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you annotate something with **@Pointcut** you are basically defining the pointcut signature, you can not do any sort of processing in there. What you need to do is to create another method which has all the processing details and uses the pointcut signature you evaluated above. Hence,

```
@Pointcut("execution(public void com.myproj.service.myagg.listener.MyMessageConsumer.handleMessage(..))")
public void myPointcutSignature(){
//This basically has nothing :)  
}

@Around("myPointcutSignature")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();
    boolean isExceptionThrown = false;
   //And the remaining code
  -------
 }
```

Hope this works. Also remember that ProceedingJoinPoint can be used only with @Around advice.